# How to add a user control to a context menu

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, contextmenu

In my Windows Form Application, I have created a context menu for a panel. I have also created a User Control, which I want to appear as a menu item on my menu.
Currently, I can create an instance of the User Control when I click an item - "properties" - on the menu, but I would like it to appear to actually be a part of the menu, like this:
[image: An example I mocked up in Paint]

Here is my current code for adding menu items and the event handler that is called when you mouse over the option.

```
private static void SetUpContextMenu()
{
    mnu = new ContextMenu();
    MenuItem mnuAdd = new MenuItem("Add child");
    MenuItem mnuDel = new MenuItem("Delete");
    MenuItem mnuProperties = new MenuItem("Change properties");
    mnuAdd.Click += new EventHandler(mnuAdd_Click);
    mnuDel.Click += new EventHandler(mnuDel_Click);
    //display the user control when this event occurs
    mnuProperties.Select += MnuProperties_Select;
    mnu.MenuItems.AddRange(new MenuItem[] { mnuAdd, mnuDel, mnuProperties });
}

private static void MnuProperties_Select(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //create new instance of User Control (NodeInspector)
    //add NodeInspector to context menu
}
```

Does anyone know how I can add this user control to my context menu?
Thank you!

Comment: Is `NodeInspector` inheriting from [`UserControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Host it in a [`ToolStripControlHost`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-wrap-a-windows-forms-control-with-toolstripcontrolhost).

Comment: @CDove yes it is.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I had a look into this just now, but as far as I can see, the ToolStripControlHost only works for a ContextMenuStrip. Is there a similar control that would work for a ContextMenu?

Comment: It's for `ContextMenuStrip`.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I'm using a ContextMenu though, not a strip